# Change default value of the optional argument of \\, also in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, line-spacing

I use a lot of `\\` in my beamer presentations to force line breaks at nice places, and more often than not, I use `\\[5pt]` instead of the default value (which feels too cramped).

Some trial and error told me that the spacing after `\\` is dictated by `\baselineskip`.

However, extending `\baselineskip`, directly or with `\baselinestretch` or `\setstretch` from `setspace`, also increases the spacing of a lot of other elements.

So I'm looking for a way to change the default spacing after a `\\`.

Redefining the command

```
\let\oldbb\\
\renewcommand{\\}[1][5pt]{\oldbb[#1]}
```

appears to be working in normal text, but in tikz nodes, it seems that the old behavior comes back.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\let\oldbb\\
\renewcommand{\\}[1][5pt]{\oldbb[#1]}


\begin{document}

This is the expected spacing:\\
Test (default)\\
Test (5)\\[5pt]
Test (10)\\[10pt]
Test (0)\\[0pt]
Test

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Doesn't change anything
  \let\oldbb\\
  \renewcommand{\\}[1][5pt]{\oldbb[#1]}

  \node[align=left %, text width=3cm
       ] {%
    This is the default spacing:\\[5pt]
    Test (default)\\
    Test (5)\\[5pt]
    Test (10)\\[10pt]
    Test (0)\\[0pt]
    Test
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the `\node` Ti*k*Z does `\let\\=\tikz@align@newline`. Furthermore, `\tikz@align@newline` is `\pgfutil@protect\tikz@align@newline@`, so what you need to change is `\tikz@align@newline@`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\let\oldbb\\
\renewcommand{\\}[1][5pt]{\oldbb[#1]}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tikz@align@newline@}{%  The default definition had 0pt here VVV
  \unskip \pgfutil@ifnextchar [\tikz@@align@newline {\tikz@@align@newline [5pt]}%
}
% For nodes with text width
\renewcommand{\@xcentercr}[1][5pt]{%
  \addvspace{-\parskip}\vskip#1\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the expected spacing:\\
Test (default)\\
Test (5)\\[5pt]
Test (10)\\[10pt]
Test (0)\\[0pt]
Test

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Doesn't change anything
  \node[align=left] {%
    This is the default spacing:\\[5pt]
    Test (default)\\
    Test (5)\\[5pt]
    Test (10)\\[10pt]
    Test (0)\\[0pt]
    Test
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! Now I just need to understand why it doesn't work in my non-minimal beamer file...

Comment: @T.Verron Hmm... Are you doing the redefinition in the preamble of the document or inside a `frame`?

Comment: I found the problem. The node I'm using has a specified `text width`, which iirc means that the content is put in a minipage. So, I guess `minipage` has its own defininition of `\\\`?

Comment: If you know the solution for that case too, I can edit the question and let you edit your answer. Otherwise, I can make it a new question.

Comment: @T.Verron Nah, it was quite simple. In that case the ``\\`` becomes `\@centercr`, which uses `\@xcentercr` internally. I added a redefinition of that too.

Comment: Thank you very much. `:)`